# Cannot get selected value from javascript dropdown list

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have the following code for a dropdown menu

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="DataVersionDropDownButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Dataset Version
</button> 
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="DataVersionDDMenu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">    
</div>
```

It is populated dynamically

```
var datadirnames = ["NewData", "OldData", "EvenOlderData"];
        for (var i = 0; i < datadirnames.length; i++) {
            var opt = datadirnames[i];
            var el = document.createElement("a");
            el.classList = "dropdown-item";
            el.href = "#";
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").appendChild(el);
        }
```

When I select an item from the drop down menu the following is called but I cannot access the item selected or get it to be displayed as the text for the dropdown menu.

```
 $("#DataVersionDDMenu").click(function() {              
                 console.log("DropDown selected "); 
                 var e = document.getElementById("DataVersionDDMenu");
                 var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;                  

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',                   
                    url: '@Url.Action("Volumes", "DataVersionSelect", new{id = 1, com="volumes"})',
                    data: { "value": $("#DataVersionDDMenu").val() },
                    success: function (data){
                       console.log("data is " + data);
                    }
                });
             });
```

Output is:

```
DropDown selected 
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')
```

What value needs to go in document.getElementById()?, is that my problem?
There seems to be so many different ways of having and using a dropdown list that I am getting confused as new to this and haven't had any luck looking at other poster's similar questions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @Unmitigated i don't know what is selected, that is my problem. How do I get the value that the user has selected from the dropdown?

Comment: Are you somehow marking the selected item or is the dropdown being controlled by some library?

Comment: .click(function(e) { ... that click handler function receives an e, use it to figure out what was clicked instead of var e = document.getElementById("DataVersionDDMenu");. that's a weird way to build a selectable list tho. a11y constrains ..?

Comment: @ihor.eth, no 11yo constraints - please tell me a better more modern way. didn't realise this was an old way. using bootstrap 4

Comment: use <select> if you need to just select an item from the list or <datalist> if you wan to be able to typeahead/filter the list